# opencart admin panel is not loading properly

Tags: opencart, admin, panel, opencart-3

I installed Opencart 3.0.2.0,  the admin panel nothing was loaded correctly and not displayed properly.  Buttons, icons, bars, pics. Everything is missing. Buttons are not showing and working correctly. How can I solve this problem? Screenshot attached.

Regards

1. https://i.stack.imgur.com/JLVd5.png
2. https://i.stack.imgur.com/bV3UW.png
3. http://i.hizliresim.com/PD07a8.png
4. http://i.hizliresim.com/6N9Dp9.png

Comment: any javascript errors? the console output? if you are using chrome browser ctrl+ shift + I,

Comment: this is no screenshot in your post,

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JLVd5.png 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/bV3UW.png

Comment: Yes, there are a lot of errors. @mfadel http://i.hizliresim.com/PD07a8.png http://i.hizliresim.com/6N9Dp9.png

Comment: jquery is not loaded maybe this is the reason for all of these errors

Comment: first, you have to fix it make jquery load correctly, check that path if the file is there, or has the correct permissions,

Comment: I don't know how to install jquery and fix it.